Continue on graphical modeler steps if field exists else abandon
I am building a model with graphical modeler in QGIS. Let us assume the model has 10 steps. In step 3 or so, I would like to check if a field in the vector exists. If a field by a given name exists, model should proceed further. If the field does not exist in the vector layer, then skip all subsequent steps. Is such a check possible with graphical modeler in QGIS?

Please check: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34804#:~:text=Conditional%20branch%20can%20support%20this%2C%20yes.%20Took%20me%20a%20few%20tries%20to%20figure%20out%20what%20the%20expression%20ought%20to%20be%2C%20but%20it%27s%20a%20simple%20not%2Dnull%20check.%20In%20this%20example%2C%20I%20have%20an%20optional%20input%2C%20%22Raster%20layer%20to%20crop%22%3A
